# Creating a template in java code for sending emails

Tags: java, email

My application requires sending an email.
I have created a form which when submitted sends email to the required mail id. I am able to successfully send mails.
Now I want to create a standard template for sending mails using tokens. Wherever I want to values to be included I should be able to send them using variables.
Right now I am sending it as a String.

Is using StringTokenizer helpful?
Or is there any other way?

I want to include it in my action class..

Comment: My Old company save the template in properties file with some variable. unfortunately i dont bring the code right now so i cant give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent template engine, and it's well suited to generating e-mail content.  It has a slight learning curve, but you'll be able to use real variables (like a template should allow you to do) instead of putting everything into a `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: I would like to work with StringTokenizer.
How do I add variables in between. I mean I will have a template for email. And I would like to add the variables that should be passed along. How can I do it in StringTokenizzer?

Comment: Again, I would strongly recommend against it.  You would have to place all of the content into the StringTokenizer, and you'd be editing Java code instead of text/content every time.  It's not pleasant or intuitive to do that, or use dynamic content within the Tokenizer itself.

Comment: Why you need to use StringTokenizer? If you have defined any unique syntax(like <name> or $name$) to define placeholders in your template then you can use str.replaceAll("<name>", "cya k"). I still suggest you to use some template engine.

Comment: Makoto:
I was going through freeMarker. I think It should be interesting to use. I just need to download the jar file,isnt it? And then create the template?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Velocity template for your mail. See here http://velocity.apache.org/

In this you have to create a template file where you write whatever text format you need along with placeholders. Using the velocity api you load the template file and pass the placeholders. You can also do dynamic stuff in the template file e.g. looping etc.